# How to change default indentation for JavaScript Babel and JavaScript React in VS Code?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, visual-studio-code, indentation

Writing the following piece of code in settings.json file in VS Code, I was able to override the default 4-space indentation for JavaScript:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
},
```

For some reason, this does not apply to JavaScript React and JavaScript Babel in VS Code. How can I change their default indentation in VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

press `ctrl+,` to open editor settings then in search input write 'indentation'.

It offers you related settings:
[image]

Comment: Yes, it does. But it does not show language-specific or version-specific indentation. If I change something here, it would apply to all the languages, but I want to target specifically JavaScript Babel and JavaScript React

Comment: I don't know that, keep searching.